# Single organization Hyperledger fabric n/w

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, consensus

What are the implications, If I use hyperledger fabric's blockchain for a distributed ledger for myself. I mean I 'm not having anything to do with any other Org. So this becomes my tamper proof database for certain applications or records.

Will it have trust issues? I need the consensus to be among my peers, which are say geographically distributed.

PS: I know I can use a traditional database for this, but I 'm trying to learn about Fabric use-cases here, I feel since fabric being a generic blockchain with smart contracts f/w, having it application limited to multi-party transactions would be an injustice to the potential.

Regards,
Ashish

Answer (score 3):

The concept of "org" is not restricted to independent companies. You could use a structure where the departments/divisions of your company are each separate orgs.

That said, you can indeed have a single org deployment. There won't be trust issues if you design the endorsement policies appropriately such that you require multiple peer nodes to endorse transactions.

That said, you really *should* consider using a traditional database in use cases where doing so meets your requirements. Using blockchain in contexts where it is really unnecessary overkill could impair your ability to advocate its use in another, more appropriate context.

Comment: Yes, agree with the concept of "org". I didn't want multiple orgs all-together to save myself from managing a separate set of CA for that. Since the CA alone comes with a lot of overhead (database cluster, haproxy). 

It's just I have lack of clarity for the application of blockchain using fabric :)

Answer (score 1):

One implication that comes to mind as I read this question is the difference between a database and an immutable ledger.  Tamper proof also means 'an inability to edit'.  Databases suggest data that allows for ETL but a distributed ledger simply memorializes data in a codified way.  There isn't the option to easily retrieve, modify, and store data in the blockchain-private or not.
Using the blockchain for your personal data e.g., certificates or degrees received etc is a super way to purposefully share your data with 3rd parties-if that's what you're going for you're probably on the right track.  If you want to modify any data not so much.
Trust issues will be addressed with your consensus mechanism; and geographically dispersed peers is fine.  Trust with other orgs will be a function of how you share your public/private keys.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly my thought process.